# How to move data between 2 Android phones?

Tags: data-transfer

I'm trying to move data from a Pixel3 to a Pixel1.

**Bluetooth**

I am able to pair the devices, but for some reason they are disconnected as soon as I switch to another app (to a Files app to copy data). I'm not seeing any errors.

**USB**

I am able to connect the devices via USB, but only one way! So I can move data from Pixel1 to Pixel3, but I'm not able to move data from Pixel3 to Pixel1. In settings there is a "USB controlled by..." switch, but when I press it, it tries to switch for 10 seconds and then times out. Again, no error message to tell me what went wrong.

Surely there must be a way to move data between 2 Android phones? I don't want to use a computer/cloud as an intermediary step.

Comment: What data we are talking about here? Images videos and documents? However if it is large chunk of data I'd avoid Bluetooth since I find it blantly slow. Try using WiFi direct maybe?

Comment: Small data, 2FA secrets.

Comment: I doubt that you can move 2FA secrets from one device to another. Those secrets are designed to remain on the device to avoid theft. If you want to use them on a second device use the backup codes/recovery keys and re-register your services.

Comment: Some 2FA apps allow you to backup/restore secrets.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, where you did connect between two devices?
It's highly recommended you to build connection in Service as it can be run in background for long time. 
If you're connecting two devices simply in Activity then when it's being paused or destroyed, Your connection will be destroyed either.

Comment: I paired the devices in Settings > Connections > Bluetooth. I haven't found any other way to make a Bluetooth pairing.

Comment: Are you a programmer? I thought you're coding a feature of connecting devices.

Comment: I am a programmer, but I'm not coding a feature to connecting devices. I just want to move data from one phone to another.

Comment: Well, If so, That's would be easy... There are many good apps in appstore... Just use apps to transfer your data... If you can't find a good one for your situation, I can make one for you or find one for you...